# PHP "Notice: Array to string conversion" error when inserting to SQL

Tags: php, insert

I'm trying to insert some values to my table, but i keep getting the following Notice :

`Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\process_invitation.php on line 10`

Line 10 is the insertion line in the following code :

```
if ((isset($_POST['inviter'], $_POST['opponent'])) && ($_POST['inviter'] != '' && $_POST['opponent'] != '' )) {
    $inviter = $_POST['inviter'];
    $opponent = $_POST['opponent'];
    $now = time();
    if ($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO invitations (inviter_user_id, invited_user_id, time) VALUES ('$inviter','$opponent','$now')")) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: What types are inviter and opponent?

Comment: Put your query into a string and echo it out before you run it through mysqli. What does it show?

Comment: either `$_POST['inviter']` or `$_POST['opponent']` is an array not a string.

Comment: I think you have good advice to get to the root of your problem already, so I will just add another unrelated piece of advice.  Don't store you date/time data in MySQL using unix timestamps, use the native MySQL date, datetime, or timestamp field types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried var_dumping $inviter and $opponent to see what datatype they are? Try just casting them to (string) too. Also, it's a good idea to use parameterised queries with mysqli. As it stands, you're leaving yourself wide open to SQL injections.

Comment: I've now seen the second parameter is really an `array` so ill try change it.  Can you please specify regarding the `parameterised queries` ? what is it ?  Thanks

Comment: @SagiLow try this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 2):

Print the output of variables & you will know where the problem is:

```
print_r($inviter);
print_r($opponent);
```

Make sure to extract value from the array before mysql insertion.